# List Compare with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two different Classes:

```
class X
{
    public int TX1 { get; set; }
    public string TX2 { get; set; }

    public string OX1 { get; set; }
}

class Y
{
    public int TY1 { get; set; }
    public string TY2 { get; set; }
    public string TY3 { get; set; }

    public string OY1 { get; set; }
}
```

eg:

```
OX1 => 1,2,3,4
OY1 => 2,1
```

Now i need to check atleast one value match is found.
Suggest me some solution using `LINQ`.

Comment: Could you clarify how you'd want to match? Between two collections of X/Y or just between two strings? Preferably with code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are you trying to find any class Y for a class X where any value in OY1 exists in OX1?

Comment: what's your question? What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: i want to compare each value of X=>Ox1.split(',') to y=>OY1.split(',')

Comment: y do u want to mark as negative wen u people cannot answer ....

Comment: Because the question is too vague and undetailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var listOY1 = OY1.Split(',');
bool b = OX1.Split(',').Any(x=>listOY1.Contains(x));
```